# Dealing with Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when iterating over Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Not an Excel/VB expert but I keep getting

> Run time error: 9: Subscript out of range

The error is occurring at the `For Each` line.  Not sure why. I'm trying to copy worksheets from one workbook to another workbook.

The Workbook `strFileName` is being open successfully and the workbook does contain two other worksheets but code is failing on next line. I've seen similar posts regarding similar issue but have not had any luck. Any advice would be great. (I'm using Excel 2010) Thanks

```
Workbooks.Open (strFileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(strFileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks(activeWKBook).Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks(strFileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks(activeWKBook).Worksheets(total)
Next sheet
```

Comment: Try this `Workbooks(strFileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks(activeWKBook).Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strFileName` contains the full path of the workbook.
So you cannot use it in `Workbooks(strFileName)` since it only expects the workbook name.

This is how you should do it:

```
Dim wbName As String
wbName = Split(strFileName, "\")(Ubound(Split(strFileName, "\"))) ' Get the WB Name

For Each sheet In Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets
   ' Other cool stuff goes here
Next
```

But it is better to be explicit right away so you'll not have to worry about default path separator.
Remember that it is not always `\`. So I suggest you try below.

```
Dim myWB As Workbook
Set myWB = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In myWB.Worksheets
    With Thisworkbook ' Explicitly refer to the workbook that contains the code
        sheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With
Next
```

Remember, you need to use `ThisWorkbook` in place of `ActiveWorkbook`.
Why? Because the moment you open the other workbook, the currently opened workbook becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`.

So to copy all sheets from the opened workbook to the workbook that contains the code, use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! Used your second approach and it worked. One question, rather than appending new sheets into the "Thisworkbook" workbook is there a way to explicitly declare a worksheet that the data should be loaded into. So say I have a worksheet named "Copy Data" in Thisworkbook, is there a way to copy the data into this specific worksheet?

Comment: @tony Yes. But you'll have to copy and paste the contents of the sheets.